# swagger2 show whitelabel page error on swagger-ui.html

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I try to implement `swagger2` in my project on spring boot. I add this dependencies in my `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also, I have spring-security (basic auth)

```
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                    "/configuration/ui",
                    "/swagger-resources/**",
                    "/configuration/security",
                    "swagger-ui.html",
                    "/webjars/**",
                    "/configuration/**",
                    "/swagger*/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().sessionManagement().disable();
```

When I try `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` i get whitelabel error page `- type=Not Found, status=404.` But `http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs` works fine and I see all info about API endpoints. How to fix it?

Comment: I change swagger2 version to 2.7.0 and it works.

Answer (score 2):

In SpringFox 3 the Swagger ui location changed to `/swagger-ui/index.html`. If you are using Spring Boot, you should use `springfox-boot-starter`, which automatically registers this endpoint. Otherwise you have to "explicitly register using a resource handler configurer"[2].

Relevant References:

- https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3441 [1]
- http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#regular-spring-mvc [2]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. v2/api-docs was working but changed the address to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index and now it works